# Splitting using newline character in bash command substitutions

Tags: bash, quoting

Say I have a directory with three files with names including spaces: `a b`, `c d`, and `e f`. And I want to use `vi` to edit the first two files. The bash command I want is

```
vi "a b" "c d"
```

I also want to get the first two lines of `ls` command using `head`, such that I can substitute the first command's parameters:

```
ls | head -n 2
```

However, if I run `vi $(ls | head -n 2)`, it is equivalent to `vi a b c d`, which is not what I want, because the output inside `$()` is splitted by space and newline. Is there any way to split the output only by newline?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); read [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to split the output only by newline?

Yes, set `IFS` to just a newline (by default it contains a space, a tab and a newline):

```
IFS=$'\n'
vi $(ls | head -n 2)
```

<sub>(`$''` is nonstandard but works in Bash/ksh/zsh, and much prettier than the alternatives.)</sub>

---

That said, you still have the problem that the filenames might contain glob characters. To disable globbing, you'd need to use `set -f` first (and `set +f` after to re-enable it). And also, if your filenames contain newlines, that won't work, but I suppose you knew that.